# Server 2012 - Hyper V Manager, RemoteFX missing From Hardware List

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, remotefx

I've installed Remote Desktop Services and Hyper-V on a server running Windows Server 2012. The Hyper-V settings are showing my GPU as selected for use with RemoteFX as below

[image]

However when I go to add the hardware to a virtual machine it does not show up in the list of available hardware.

[image: VM]

Sorry, If I'm a little light on details, I'm not sure where to start on this I've been searching for answers for the better part of the day without much luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RemoteFX does not work with Generation 2 (UEFI based) VM's with the current version of Hyper-V.

You will need to remake the VM to be Generation 1 instead to be able to use RemoteFX.

A Generation 2 VM:
[image]

A Generation 1 VM:
[image]