# RemoteFX from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-10-preview, remotefx

Is it possible to use RemoteFX if client is Windows 8.1 Pro and virtual machine is Windows 10 [Generation 1](https://superuser.com/a/665020/69300)? I don't see RemoteFX options in Hyper-V Manager or RDC? How I can enable RemoteFX?

Can I have RemoteRX in Hyper-V Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8.1 uses [Client Hyper‑V](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/hyper-v-run-virtual-machines), not Server Hyper‑V, which used by Windows Server.

And Client Hyper‑V [doesn't include RemoteFX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh857623.aspx):

> There are some features included in Hyper-V on server that are not
>   included in Client Hyper-V. These include the following:
>
> The Remote FX
>
> capability to virtualize GPUs
>
> Live migration of virtual machines from one host to another
>
> Hyper-V Replica
>
> Virtual Fibre Channel
>
> 32-bit SR-IOV networking
>
> Shared .vhdx

Comment: this sucks so bad. so we can not use gpu virtualization on windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use vGPU only in Windows 10 Anniversary Update's Client Hyper-V or newer (like Host, not Guest), but not in Win 8 or 8.1, sorry.